# Set Cookie not working (nextJs + express)

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, next.js, setcookie

I'm trying to set the cookie from my express backend to my nextjs front end using the response.setHeader, but it's not working, I get my json response but no cookies are set, I used postman to make some tests and in postman it did set the cookies as it should be.
NextJs version is 13.0.2, express version is 4.18.2 and cookie version is 0.5.0

My express server:

```
export const loginUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  //limpa os cookies
  res.clearCookie("accessToken", { httpOnly: true });

  if (email !== "" && password !== "") {
    try {
      const foundUser: any = await prisma.users.findFirst({
        where: {
          email,
          password,
        },
      });

      try {
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
          { id: foundUser.id, email },
          "dspaojdspoadsaodksa",
          {
            expiresIn: "10s",
          }
        );
        const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
          { id: foundUser.id, email },
          "dsaoindsadmnsaosda",
          {
            expiresIn: "50s",
          }
        );

        const savedRefresh = await prisma.refresh_token.upsert({
          where: {
            users_id: foundUser.id,
          },
          update: {
            access_token: accessToken,
            refresh_tk: refreshToken,
            users_id: foundUser.id,
          },
          create: {
            access_expires_in: "",
            refresh_expires_in: "",
            access_token: accessToken,
            refresh_tk: refreshToken,
            users_id: foundUser.id,
          },
        });

        res.setHeader(
          "Set-Cookie",
          cookie.serialize("accessToken", accessToken, {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15, //15 minutes
            httpOnly: true, // The cookie only accessible by the web server
          })
        );

        res.json({ accessToken, user: { email }, ok: true });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("refresh cant be created");
        res.send({ message: "refresh cant be created" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.send({ message: "user not found" });
    }
  } else {
    res.json({ message: "token creation failed" });
  }
};
```

My nextJs front-end:

```
const handleLogin = async (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const email = (event?.target as any).email.value;
    const password = (event?.target as any).password.value;

    if (email === "" || password === "") {
      setError(true);
      return;
    }

    const data = {
      email,
      password,
    };

    const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });

    const userData = await resp.json();
    console.log(userData);
  };
```

Comment: Do your frontend and backend run on different domains (`fronend.com` vs. `backend.org`)? If so, the browser might block the cookie as a third-party cookie.

Comment: Yes, they run on different domains, do you know how to fix it, or how to see if this is the problem?

Comment: Blocked third-party cookies should be visible in the browser's network tab, under "Cookies".

Comment: There are no cookies in the cookies tab.

Comment: Have you found any solutions yet? I am experiencing the same problem.